# How can i recall a function after every component rerender in livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, ag-grid, laravel-livewire

I have a function that initializes the ag-grid table in window.onload, but after rerender the table disappears. My problem is that I don't know how to emit an event that will trigger this function so that it is called after the rerender and not before it. I am using the latest version of livewire and blade templates.